# React input field JavaScript/JSON injection prevention

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss

Can you provide me with some example code for react input field validation to prevent JavaScript/JSON input? For example, to prevent Cross Site Scripting attacks.

What I am looking for is a way of validating an input field in the react app to prevent the storage of JS/JSON input insecurely.

So for example, when parsing the user input before sending it server side, and also to load some server side data, before rendering it to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function before when you wants to send data to your server.
this function prevent XSS attack in javascript.

```
function escapeOutput(toOutput){
    return toOutput.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/\</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/\>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/\"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/\'/g, '&#x27')
        .replace(/\//g, '&#x2F');
}
```